# What does "is gross of fees" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, terminology

I'm reading a [fund portfolio](http://doc.morningstar.com/LatestDoc.aspx?clientid=hsbcmpseng&key=37d063d8055f3f90&documenttype=124&investmentid=F00000M8CT) and it says "Performance is gross of fees."

So if performance = 10%
and fees = 0.1%

does that mean that the real performance is 10% or 9.9%?

Answer (score 1):

> The gross-of-fees return is defined as the return on investments reduced by any trading expenses

It is therefore generally considered to be the best measure for comparing a firm's real investment management performance.

Note that this sort of language is technical and not part of the general vocabulary of native speakers of English.  A web search found the defintion and much more: see the ["Global Investment Performance Standards"](https://www.gipsstandards.org/standards/Documents/Archive/gs_fees_clean.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I would read this to mean that the real 'net' return is 9.9%
In business, we talk of gross profit and net profit. Net profit is that which remains after the deduction of all operating costs.